# module export scenario confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I dont understand certain scenarios of `module.exports` concept of `nodejs`.

math.js

```
var add = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
}

multiply = function(a, b){
    return a * b;
}
```

**Scenario 1:**

app.js

```
require("./math")

//can I use add?
//can I use multiply?
```

**Scenario 2:**

app.js

```
var math = require("./math")

//can I use math.add?
//can I use math.multiply?
```

I have put down my questions inside each scenarios.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you check here http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html?

Comment: @elclanrs I have but didn't understand the scenario which i have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To add functions and objects to the root of your
>   module, you can add them to the special exports object.
>
> Variables local to the module will be private, as though the module
>   was wrapped in a function. In this example the variable PI is private
>   to circle.js.

Both of your scenarios wont work(as you would have noticed if you had just tried it).
Everything you want to use needs to be assigned to the `exports` property on the (module-)local `module` object.

See the example on [nodejs.org/api/modules.html](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

EDIT:
Imagine require doing the following

```
(function (module, exports) {
  var im_local = 123;
  im_global = 321;
  // Your module code here
})(module, module.exports);
return module.exports;
```

Note that `im_global` is actually invalid by newer javascript standards but will not throw an error when not in strict mode because of
backwards compatibilty / quirks mode behavior of the V8 javascript engine.

Comment: I dont know if you have tried it but in `scenario 1` you can actually use `multiply`. Plz try it.

Comment: You're right it works because you're assigning ´multiply´ to an undefined variable, javascript will then bubble up to resolve that variable and ends up at the ´global´ object and assigns ´multiply´ as a property to it. Using ´"use strict"´ would've thrown an error on you there. So while it technically works its not how node modules are supposed to be used. This is why i stated that scenario 1  does not work since you cannot use add. Since its defined locally. Google "javascript scope" to learn more about scoping in javascript.

Comment: on your point then do we even need to do the `require` statement or since its on the global scope then i should be able to use it no matter wht. right?

Comment: Its not on global scope, see my updated answer on that. And yes you probably want to still use require since you would not want to write your whole application inside one file.

Comment: *"do we even need to do the require statement"* Of course. If you don't require the module, it's not going to be executed.